# How can I cast a generic to an executable function?

Tags: generics, typescript

Given the following contrived code example, where `T` may or may not be a `Function`, how can I cast it in Typescript in a way which will allow me to execute it (assuming this is possible at all)?

```
class Test<T> {
    constructor(public value: T) {}

    method() {
        if (this.value instanceof Function) {
            let fn = <Function>this.value; // [ts] Neither type 'T' nor type 'Function' is assignable to the other.
            fn();
        }
    }
}

let test = new Test(() => {});
test.method();
```

If this is solvable, can I cast it to a specific function signature as well, as in the following?

```
let fn: (input: T) => any = <(input: T) => Test<T>>this.value;
```

I have a semi-legitimate use case for it (can add background, if necessary), but I can't help but wonder if I'm hammering a square peg through a round hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Neither type 'T' nor type 'Function' is assignable to the other.

You can force it with a double assertion:

```
let fn = this.value as any as Function;
```

## More

This is covered here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html

## More

> Can I use the double assertion with a function interface,

Sure:

```
let value: number;
let fn = this.value as any as (input:string)=>any;
```

Comment: Interesting. Can I use the double assertion with a function interface, similar to the `(input: T) => Test<T>` above?

Comment: @dvlsg sure. Added to answer